# Foreign and Primary Key Conceptual Questions

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am a newbie at SQL/PostgreSQL, and I had a conceptual question about foreign keys and keys in general:

Let's say I have two tables: Table `A` and Table `B`.

`A` has a bunch of columns, two of which are `A.id, A.seq`. The primary key is `btree(A.id, A.seq)` and it has a foreign key constraint that `A.id` references `B.id`. Note that `A.seq` is a sequential column (first row has value 1, second has 2, etc).

Now say `B` has a bunch of columns, one of which is the above mentioned `B.id`. The primary key is `btree(B.id)`.

I have the following questions:

1. What exactly does `btree` do? What is the significance of having two column names in the btree rather than just one (as in `btree(B.id)`).
2. **Why is it important that `A` references `B` instead of `B` referencing `A`? Why does order matter when it comes to foreign keys??**

Thanks so much! Please correct me if I used incorrect terminology for anything.

EDIT: I am using postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A btree index stored values in sorted order, which means you can not only search for a single primary key value, but you can also efficiently search for a range of values:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id between 6060842 AND 8675309
```

PostgreSQL also supports other [index types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html), but [only btree is supported for a unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html) (for example, the primary key).

In your `B` table, the primary key being a single column `id` means that only one row can exist for each value in `id`. In other words, it is unique, and if you search for a value by primary key, it will find at most one row (it may also find zero rows if you don't have a row with that value).

The primary key in your `A` table is for `(id, seq)`. This means you can have multiple rows for each value of `id`. You can also have multiple rows for each value of `seq` as long as they are for different `id` values. The combination must be unique though. You can't have more than one row with the same pair of values.

When a foreign key in `A` references `B`, it means that the row must exist in `B` before you are allowed to store the row in `A` with the same `id` value. But the reverse is not necessary.

Example:

Suppose `B` is for users and `A` is for phones. You must store a user before you can store a phone record for that user. You can store one or more phones for that user, one per row in the `A` table. We say that a row in `A` therefore references the user row in `B`, meaning, "this phone belongs to user #1234."

But the reverse is not restricted. A user might have no phones (at least not known to this database), so there is no requirement for `B` to reference `A`. In other words, it is not required for a user to have a phone. You can store a row in `B` (the user) even if there is no row in `A` (the phones) for that user.

The reference also means you are not allowed to `DELETE FROM B WHERE id = ?` if there are rows in another table that reference that given row in `B`. Deleting that user would cause those other rows to become orphaned. No one would be able to know who those phones belonged to, if the user row they reference is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the concrete example! The nice phone/users analogy really drove it home for me.

Answer (score 1):

To your questions:

1. There are several strategies to implement unique keys. The most common one is to use an index that is "unique" using a "b-tree" strategy. That's what "btree" means in PostgreSQL.

   Having two columns in a key just depends on how you want to design your table. When you have a key with more than one column that is called a "composite key".
2. When `A` references `B`, the columns in `B` must represent a "key". The columns in `A` do not represent a key, but just a *reference* to one. In fact the values in `A` for that column can be repeated; that is, multiple rows in `A` can *point* to the same row in `B`.

Comment: Your second point was really helpful - it's a bit counterintuitive that the so called "primary key " of a table is actually just a reference to an actual key in a second table. That makes sense though.

If I could ask a follow up question then: Does this mean that `A` is a weak entity then? Because it actually just contains information relative to `B`?

That would mean that the reason `B` can't reference `A` is because it would be meaningless for a strong entity to reference a weak entity?

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure makes no sense.  Why would the primary key of A haver both `id` and `name`?  Normally it would just be `id`.  In some data models, you might have a version or timestamp added.  I can't think of a reasonable data model where `name` would also be included.

In addition, `B`'s foreign key would have to be to both `id` and `name`.

But, your question is what is `btree` for?  Most databases don't have such an option.  A primary key would typically be expressed as:

```
id int primary key;
constraint unq_t_id primary key (id);
```

`btree` is a type of index -- in fact the default type of index in all databases that I'm aware of.  Databases that have a plethora of available types of indexes -- such as Postgres -- you can specify the index type associated with the primary key.

Comment: Yes, I am using postgres (psql) and I'm not 100% sure why btree is included: I'm trying to figure that out myself haha. In terms of keys - the first table's name one is just what I called it: in reality, `A.name` is a sequential column (first row is 1, second is 2, etc). The second table does not have such a column - it's pkey is **only** `B.id`

Comment: I changed the description now to refer to that column as `A.seq` instead - hopefully that helps.